# Can't redirect crontab output to file in AWS EC2

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, cron

I'm trying to redirect the crontab output to a txt file in my AWS EC2 instance. I've tried the following, which doesn't seem to redirect the output of the crontab job (copy folder1 to folder2) to the file backup.log (I'm expecting an error output as the folders are not being copied):

```
* * * * * cp -a  home/folder1 home/folder2 >> home/backup.log 2>&1
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: @stdunbar I just edited the post to try to achieve more clarity.

Comment: I would remove the redirection and take a look at [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56683/where-is-the-cron-crontab-log).  The overall output should be saved for you.  However, the post also shows some redirection too.  Remember that paths and `home` may not be where you expect.

Comment: I actually did use grep CRON /var/log/syslog, which showed me the message: (No MTA installed, discarding output). I wanted to redirect the detailed output to a different file so I wouldn't have to install a mail service.

Answer (score 0):

I m guessing you are missing "/", EC2 won't understand path home/folder. Please try below
* * * * * cp -ar  /home/folder1 /home/folder2 >> /home/backup.log 2>&1

Comment: I actually also tried with the "/", which still didn't work. I'm not sure how to figure out what path crontab understands / uses.

Answer (score 0):

Does the user with whom cron executes permissions to write to the home directory?

You can try to run:

```
echo "test" >> /home/backup.log
```

You can also put your user's directory in the cron:

```
* * * * * cp -ar /home/folder1 /home/folder2 >> ~/backup.log 2>&1
```